# setting up pallet_session genesis keys in running chain

Tags: genesis, session, on-runtime-upgrade, validator-set

I am running a solo chain with Genesis authorities set up for AURA and GRANPA. Now I have to add new validators and for that, I am planning to add substrate_validator_set and pallet_session.
During OnRuntimeUpgrade what is the correct way to set `Keys` storage item in `pallet_session`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this code to set up the session keys during a runtime upgrade.

- https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/6334588c9db0115f6b3445ce11d02a457275b34b/relay/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L1697
- https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/blob/6334588c9db0115f6b3445ce11d02a457275b34b/relay/polkadot/src/lib.rs#L455-L479

However, there is a distinction.

BEEFY is an optional feature that allows the use of a placeholder key for genesis.

In contrast, AURA is mandatory. You must pre-generate the keys, put them into code and the validator nodes. Otherwise, your chain will probably be bricked after the runtime upgrade.

Comment: The shared example describes the change in session_keys but i am adding pallet_session first time. can you please share such example.

Comment: should i need to set Aura authorities again during migration ?

Comment: Follow that example. Replace `storage::translate` with `storage::put` or `storage::insert`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Based on my current understanding, you don't need to reset the AURA authorities. However, you should always test these on your testnet first.